# How can draw a polygon on google map using zip code of area?

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to draw the polygon (boundary) of area using zip code of that area on Google map. How can we get all longitudes and latitudes of boundary of a zip code to draw the boundary of that area. for example if I want to draw boundary of Mumbai using zip code of mumbai. Please help.

Comment: are you looking for a source of information to give you the boundaries as a polygon based on a zip code? or do you already have the information?

Comment: explained here - http://forums.asp.net/t/1753021.aspx?How+to+Draw+polygon+on+google+maps+with+latitude+and+longitude+points+stored+in+the+database+

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a source of information to give you the boundaries as a polygon based on a zip code.

Comment: Yes I am looking for a source of information to get the boundaries as a polygon based on a zip code.

Comment: You need to change question to `How can we get all longitudes and latitudes of boundary of a zip code to draw the boundary of that area?`

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick guide to build this. For more details [use this link](http://www.etechpulse.com/2014/02/get-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates.html). To see , how it works, drag points and scroll below to see exact coordinates of polygon points.

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.991625, 77.706587);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.RoadMap
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
  var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(28.525416, 79.870605),
    new google.maps.LatLng(27.190518, 77.530518),
    new google.maps.LatLng(29.013807, 77.67334)

  ];
  // Construct the polygon 
  bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    draggable: true,
    editable: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle, "dragend", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "insert_at", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "remove_at", getPolygonCoords);
  google.maps.event.addListener(bermudaTriangle.getPath(), "set_at", getPolygonCoords);
}

function getPolygonCoords() {
  var len = bermudaTriangle.getPath().getLength();
  var htmlStr = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlStr += bermudaTriangle.getPath().getAt(i).toUrlValue(5) + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = htmlStr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Get Latitude and Longitude Coordinates of a Polygon - Google Maps API v3</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 350px; width: auto;">
  </div>
  <div id="info" style="position: absolute; font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px;">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: here we have hard code Longitudes and Latitudes values. But I want these values from zip code to draw boundary of that zip code area. Means we should have all Longitudes and Latitudes for boundary of selected zip code.

Comment: So your question was to `How to get those Lat/Long from zip code`? If not, and you have those, then you can feed that to `triangleCoords` in above example, it will draw one for you.

Comment: Yes, my question is how to get these Lat/Long from zip code to draw boundary of that zip code area.

Comment: @user3783446, if you see at your question it says `How can draw a polygon on google map using zip code of area?` and I responded to that, so if you don't need this and need new question, then post one.